# Matching text surrounded by whitespace in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with lines like this:

```
|   hello world   |       foo bar!   |
```

I want to be able to match the `hello world` and `foo bar!` so I can, say, reverse the two phrases without caring about the whitespace between phrases and pipe characters.

So far I have this, but is there a less verbose regex that will do the same thing?

```
:s/| \+\(.*[^ ]\) \+| \+\(.*[^ ]\) \+|/| \2 | \1 |/g
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the whitespace between, why not preserve it?

```
:s/\(|[^|]*\)\(|[^|]*\)|/\2\1|/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) or very magic flags to use less slashes, but it doesn't help too much.

```
:s/\v\| +(.*[^ ]) +\| +(.*[^ ]) +\|/| \2 | \1 |/g
```

If you notice, you have the same regex twice in a row (\| +(.*[^ ]) +). You might be able to use that along with {2} to get it shorter.